# Cant find StringField inside wtforms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to import StringField from wtforms but pycharm doesn't recognise the import.  I already tried `pip install flask-wtf` and `pip install flask_wtf` but nothing seems to have the basic `StringField`. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[StringField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.StringField) and [PasswordField](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.PasswordField) belongs to the package [wtforms.fields](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#module-wtforms.fields).

```
class wtforms.fields.StringField(default field arguments)
class wtforms.fields.PasswordField(default field arguments)
```

So you should import in this way:

```
from wtforms.fields import StringField, PasswordField
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because there are several versions of Python installed you should specify the version while installing the package. Assuming you're using python2.7.

```
sudo -H pip2 install wtforms
sudo -H pip2 install flask-wtf
```

You can import them the way you did:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, RadioField #etcetera
```